# Есть ли функциональность сортировки вопросов по количеству просмотров?

Tags: предложение, поиск

Пытался получить список вопросов, в котором бы самый верхний имел бы больше всего просмотров.

Есть ли возможность получить такой результат средствами интерфейса ru.so?

Comment: Только свои вопросы в профиле можно так сортировать.

Comment: Разве что в поиске указывать `views:10000` и если вопросов мало/много то регулировать соответственно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам не сильно важно видеть список в реальном времени, то вот вам запрос из SE DataExplorer (данные afair раз в неделю обновляются).

http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/359649/most-viewed-questions