# Сортировка ответов/вопросов по количеству просмотров

Tags: предложение

Предлагаю добавить в профиль пользователей возможность сортировки вопросов и ответов (в первую очередь ответов) по количеству просмотров.

Это нужно для идеалистов - людей желающих бесконечно улучшать качество своих ответов.
Например кто-то дал хороший ответ, но не в полном объеме, как мог бы.
Обычная человеческая лень и нежелание топать старый вопрос не заставит автора ответа улучшать его качество спустя пару недель без внешнего фактора.
Внешним факторов может стать:

- уточняющий комментарий к ответу
- большой счетчик просмотров этого вопроса

---

Зададимся таким вопросом:
**Стоит ли улучшать качество своих старых ответов?**
Думаю, что ответ: **стоит**.

Тогда зададим себе другой вопрос:
**А какие ответы тогда лучше всего улучшать с целью повышения качества контента?**
Ответ: Те, у которых наибольшее число просмотров.

---

В идеале желательно иметь отдельный счетчик просмотров **Просмотры пришедшие с поисковых систем или сторонних ресурсов** и сортировать по нему.

---

Дисклеймер:
Есть вот такой вопрос:
[Есть ли функциональность сортировки вопросов по количеству просмотров?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232/)
но у меня [feature-request](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), а не вопрос.

Comment: Нравится идея, поддерживаю.

Comment: [Ответ об этом на метамете](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340461/5812238), [запрос к SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/609285/answers-by-question-views)