# Нужна кнопка для сортировки списков вопросов по просмотрам

Tags: предложение, дизайн

**Что предлагаю:**

Сейчас есть возможность отсортировать все вопросы (то меткам, например) по времени и голосам. Была бы крайне полезна возможность сортировки также и по просмотрам.

**Чем это полезно:**

Сортировка по голосам показывает оценку вопросов активной частью пользователей. Но при этом часто мнение активной части пользователей не коррелирует с ЦА. В качестве примера - вопрос с **16 000** *просмотров* (т.е. около 10/день) и всего **одним** *голосом за* (второй - мой сегодняшний):

[Как правильно подключить jar библиотеку к проекту в Eclipse?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/101595/)

Таким образом у нас нет сейчас легко доступного инструмента для поиска популярных вопросов во имя написания к ним хороших ответов.

**Вопросы:**

1. Может я плохо искал и такая кнопка имеется?
2. Если нет - то насколько реально её реализовать?
3. Если это реально - то когда ждать?

**Схожие вопросы:**

1. [Сортировка-ответов-вопросов-по-количеству-просмотров](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) - тут речь про вопросы/ответы в профиле, это уже есть, ответ надо пометить как выполненный.
2. [Есть ли функциональность сортировки вопросов по количеству просмотров?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) - в ответах и комментах только предложения вручную вбивать лимиты просмотров в поиск или пользоваться устаревшими на неделю данными.

Comment: 1. Такая кнопка имеется - смотрите ответ по второй ссылке. 2. На мете нет выполненных вопросов. Есть только те, которые помогли больше других

Comment: @Oceinic, 1. Это ведь просто запрос к базе данных на отдельном сайте... А мне-то охота кнопочку на ru-SO. 2. Есть метка "статус-завершено" для подобных случаев.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такая сортировка, с большой вероятностью не будет добавлена в функционал сайта, так как:

- согласно внутренним данным, она бы использовалась крайне редко;
- крайне тяжело постоянно поддерживать релевантность выборки, в следствии большого входящего трафика.

Для поиска таких вопросов мы рекомендуем использовать [внутренние фильтры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), например, ограничения по количеству вопросов:

> [views:1000](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A1000)

Также можно использовать [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/) для формирования своей выборки. Например

```
select top 1000 [Id] as [Post Link], Score, ViewCount 
from Posts 
order by ViewCount desc
```

Существует [интересная выбора вопросов с наибольшим количеством просмотров или отзывов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits).

Если вы ищите полезные вопросы, вы можете воспользоваться специальными инструментами «просмотра отзывов от анонимных пользователей», которые доступны всем участникам с 10К+ репутации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback.

---

Информацию для ответа брал на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/).